# What should I do if I'm unsatisfied with my recent roof replacement?

Tags: roofing

I had my roof replaced this past summer . The old roof was torn off and new insulation and a whole new roof.  It is a flat roof, new plywood and two layer torch on, on a 12x60 mobile home . The roof has leaked in 4 different places over the past 8 months.  The roofer has been cooperative and I will be meeting with him to discuss this. He has already fixed the torch on and said he was 100 % sure it would not leak, it leaked. So I would like to ask that the whole roof be replaced, is this reasonable? Also what happens to wet insulation in the ceiling? I have all work in writing and a five year guarantee. He told me he is insured. What course of action should I take?

Answer (score 4):

As a contractor, I will share with you an approach that may help.

First of all, you need to document the current leak with pictures, dates etc. When you communicate with your roofing contractor, be calm and polite, explain precisely the problem and ask to witness his/her inspection. Explain that since this is the second occurrence of the leak since the new roof installation, you are concerned that water may have compromised the insulation and framing and is a potential cause of mold or rot and must be addressed. Tell the contractor that you insist on having an infra-red scan inspection of the effected area to detect any current moisture in the cavity before any more repairs are made. If the roofer is not willing to do this, tell them that you are terribly sorry we could not reach a mutually reasonable solution. Calmly but firmly state that you now have no other choice than to have this scan done yourself and that subsequent repairs will be made by another contractor and the total costs will be litigated in a civil action against him/her. Carefully and concisely summarize your conversation and send a letter with your demands via certified mail immediately after your meeting. If the contractor does not respond favorably after written notification, contact the BBB, and licencing bureau of your town or state. If none of this induces the contractor to act, proceed to having another contractor do the scans and repairs. Follow through with civil action, usually small claims on both the contractor and his/her insurance company.

Comment: `If the contractor does not respond favorably after written notification` ... Another good contact to reach sometimes is your local news station. That will either pressure your contractor/roofer or the news station may do a story and that will help your civil case with evidence and proof of attempted contact to resolve it before court.

Comment: @Jen:  let me know how you make out.

Answer (score 1):

Meet with the gentlemen and ask him to describe his approach to how he is going to stop the leaks. This is the modern era, ask him to take photo's with his smartphone (or yours if he does not have one) and then email the photo's to you, this prevents you from getting on the roof.

Then.

I would call another roofing professional in your area,  Many offer free estimates. Explain the situation you are in and ask the roofer to look at the roof, and give him the info the former roofer provided you (leaks, where they are located, how he was going to attempt to fix them)  and ask his opinion.  Unfortunately you are dealing with water, and that can lead water damage, and serious problems.  Do not be alarmed, but be assertive in your actions.